# Mention start from this line and at specific line with opencsv

Tags: java, opencsv

This is the format of the file one will be getting after the end of market. Looking from the format of the file, I have decided to use opencsv for reading the data. Could you please tell me how to make this work as the previous one is working?

**Original CSV file**

```
,05-Jan-2016
The Nifty witnessed an intraday movement of about 67.95 points.The closing index was 0.09 % down as compared to the previous closing index.

, Traded Value (Rs. In Crores), 17657.69
, Traded Quantity (in Lakhs), 14100.76
, Number of Trades, 7865865
, Total Market Capitalisation (Rs. Crores), 9752722.53

,INDEX,PREVIOUS CLOSE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,GAIN/LOSS
,Nifty 50,      7791.30,      7828.40,      7831.20,      7763.25,      7784.65,-6.65
,Nifty IT,     11029.25,     11082.60,     11084.60,     10945.20,     10997.15,-32.1
,Nifty Next 50,     19956.85,     20031.05,     20085.40,     19925.60,     20068.75,111.9
,Nifty Bank,     16599.15,     16652.05,     16670.20,     16474.85,     16542.50,-56.65
,Nifty Midcap 100,     13429.40,     13488.20,     13553.75,     13415.00,     13546.20,116.8
,Nifty 500,      6630.80,      6659.85,      6664.10,      6614.95,      6639.50,8.7
,Nifty 100,      7957.90,      7994.40,      7997.85,      7933.45,      7959.85,1.95
,Nifty Midcap 50,      3425.25,      3444.90,      3469.80,      3412.10,      3464.25,39
,Nifty Realty,       172.40,       173.40,       176.20,       172.35,       175.55,3.15
,Nifty Infra,      2725.85,      2738.90,      2747.75,      2715.15,      2723.55,-2.3
,Nifty Energy,      8468.60,      8510.50,      8580.00,      8492.95,      8555.00,86.4
,Nifty FMCG,     20087.80,     20087.35,     20141.60,     19994.50,     20047.45,-40.35
,Nifty MNC,      9520.80,      9547.80,      9559.25,      9459.35,      9492.90,-27.9
,Nifty Pharma,     11733.70,     11803.25,     11812.00,     11689.90,     11741.50,7.8
,Nifty PSE,      3110.50,      3127.95,      3142.30,      3106.70,      3133.60,23.1
,Nifty PSU Bank,      2806.65,      2829.45,      2829.45,      2763.25,      2767.65,-39
,Nifty Serv Sector,     10072.75,     10123.05,     10123.05,     10009.95,     10043.05,-29.7
,India VIX,16.8350,16.8350,16.8350,15.5675,16.7025,-0.1325
,Nifty Auto,      8142.85,      8181.90,      8205.85,      8110.60,      8124.35,-18.5
,Nifty Metal,      1804.90,      1818.15,      1874.45,      1808.05,      1862.70,57.8
,Nifty Media,      2572.30,      2589.15,      2610.50,      2581.85,      2593.75,21.45
,Nifty Small 100,      5648.60,      5676.15,      5718.40,      5642.00,      5696.30,47.7
,Nifty 200,      4138.20,      4157.05,      4159.30,      4126.65,      4141.80,3.6
,Nifty Div Opps 50,      1894.90,      1902.90,      1904.20,      1887.85,      1894.30,-.6
,Nifty Commodities,      2415.45,      2429.00,      2451.90,      2416.25,      2443.85,28.4
,Nifty Consumption,      3562.60,      3570.00,      3578.60,      3560.80,      3568.35,5.75
,Nifty Fin Service,      6909.30,      6942.30,      6942.30,      6873.55,      6891.65,-17.65
,Nifty50 Div Point,        95.23,        95.23,        95.23,        95.23,        95.23,0
,Nifty100 Liq 15,      3020.00,      3039.15,      3040.75,      3005.55,      3017.85,-2.15
,Nifty CPSE,      2063.05,      2077.00,      2087.85,      2064.85,      2083.55,20.5
,Nifty GrowSect 15,      5116.05,      5135.50,      5136.10,      5089.55,      5103.25,-12.8
,Nifty50 PR 2x Lev,      2943.55,      2971.05,      2972.20,      2921.85,      2938.00,-5.55
,Nifty50 PR 1x Inv,       503.05,       500.75,       504.95,       500.65,       503.60,.55
,Nifty50 TR 2x Lev,      3441.60,      3473.75,      3475.10,      3416.25,      3435.10,-6.5
,Nifty50 TR 1x Inv,       465.15,       463.05,       466.90,       462.95,       465.65,.5
,Nifty50 Value 20,      3508.70,      3526.10,      3526.10,      3483.05,      3506.30,-2.4

,ADVANCES,1099
,DECLINES,478
,UNCHANGED,49

,Total securities that have hit their price bands today,161

,TOP 25 Securities Today :
,SYMBOL,SERIES,PREV. CLOSE,CLOSE PRICE,%VAR, VALUE(Rs Crs)
,RELINFRA,EQ,       599.95,       613.00,2.18,621.82
,TATASTEEL,EQ,       256.90,       274.30,6.77,405.3
,JETAIRWAYS,EQ,       732.95,       738.80,0.8,385.78
,RELIANCE,EQ,       995.30,      1005.15,0.99,342.81
,SBIN,EQ,       220.70,       217.75,-1.34,330.84
,TCS,EQ,      2369.60,      2348.95,-0.87,315.14
,RELCAPITAL,EQ,       451.70,       461.30,2.13,292.35
,DLF,EQ,       118.40,       118.40,0,283.9
,HDFC,EQ,      1216.70,      1209.40,-0.6,283.65
,INFY,EQ,      1078.90,      1074.05,-0.45,265.6
,TATAMOTORS,EQ,       377.05,       374.45,-0.69,260.42
,AXISBANK,EQ,       438.40,       436.45,-0.44,243.63
,MARUTI,EQ,      4580.65,      4566.95,-0.3,233.07
,INDIGO,EQ,      1262.10,      1252.95,-0.72,225.58
,ICICIBANK,EQ,       255.55,       256.70,0.45,207.92
,LT,EQ,      1255.95,      1256.90,0.08,207.51
,WOCKPHARMA,EQ,      1578.40,      1579.70,0.08,175.02
,AUROPHARMA,EQ,       844.30,       863.50,2.27,165.09
,LUPIN,EQ,      1795.15,      1783.05,-0.67,156.59
,CADILAHC,EQ,       320.80,       313.60,-2.24,153.08
,IGL,EQ,       519.25,       556.45,7.16,152.68
,JSWSTEEL,EQ,      1044.70,      1083.10,3.68,152.46
,YESBANK,EQ,       705.75,       707.70,0.28,146.15
,SUNPHARMA,EQ,       799.10,       800.50,0.18,130.67
,ITC,EQ,       325.10,       324.85,-0.08,126.06

,Top Five Nifty 50 Gainers:
,SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE PRICE,PREV.CLOSE,%CHANGE
,TATASTEEL,EQ,       274.30,       256.90,6.77
,VEDL,EQ,        92.40,        88.95,3.88
,GAIL,EQ,       372.25,       359.80,3.46
,HINDALCO,EQ,        82.60,        80.75,2.29
,ASIANPAINT,EQ,       900.65,       880.80,2.25

,Top Five Nifty 50 Losers:
,SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE PRICE,PREV.CLOSE,%CHANGE
,BANKBARODA,EQ,       148.10,       151.20,-2.05
,PNB,EQ,       110.60,       112.80,-1.95
,SBIN,EQ,       217.75,       220.70,-1.34
,COALINDIA,EQ,       325.80,       330.20,-1.33
,HINDUNILVR,EQ,       847.95,       859.00,-1.29

,Securities Price Volume Data in Normal market
,SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE PRICE,TRADED VALUE ,TRADED QUANTITY
,20MICRONS,EQ,        35.55,                  2653403.85,74075
,3IINFOTECH,EQ,         5.40,                 25633472.05,4808212
,3MINDIA,EQ,     10784.35,                  5855577.55,541
,549,MF,        10.00,                       20.00,2
,8KMILES,EQ,      2399.90,                264312331.00,109959
,A2ZINFRA,EQ,        27.10,                  9392452.80,346510
,AARTIDRUGS,EQ,       590.10,                  5603896.70,9464
,AARTIIND,EQ,       523.60,                 10381235.80,19846
,AARVEEDEN,EQ,        65.60,                   356074.25,5463
,ABAN,EQ,       230.30,                263146228.65,1135780
,ABB,EQ,      1094.55,                 77524234.90,69794
,ABBOTINDIA,EQ,      5878.10,                  6685338.95,1132
,ABCIL,EQ,       228.95,                  7744918.15,33421
,ABGSHIP,EQ,        72.65,                 31874042.30,435361
,ABIRLANUVO,EQ,      2293.80,               1220488373.15,543403
,ACCELYA,EQ,       937.50,                  6480492.00,6921
,ACE,EQ,        47.30,                 11451206.85,243448
,ACROPETAL,EQ,         4.05,                  1158446.85,282119
,ADANIENT,EQ,        88.60,                465660134.95,5341021
,ADANIPOWER,EQ,        34.30,                410584609.30,12091589
,ADANITRANS,EQ,        38.80,                123528731.15,3159929
,ADFFOODS,EQ,        94.85,                 14323503.70,150469
,ADHUNIK,EQ,        16.05,                  7945668.10,502188
,ADI,EQ,       249.95,                  1604853.45,6419
,ADLABS,EQ,       140.30,                 26302087.10,188134
,ADORWELD,EQ,       316.30,                  2249788.95,7141
,ADSL,EQ,        61.60,                 68661767.95,1093223
,ADVANIHOTR,EQ,        57.50,                  1303275.60,22402
,ADVANTA,EQ,       440.95,                149001835.40,340794
,AEGISCHEM,EQ,       109.50,                 23773868.70,219042
,AFL,EQ,        87.10,                  4872374.75,55602
,AGARIND,EQ,       184.30,                  6863591.25,36886
,AGCNET,EQ,        94.55,                  1075412.65,11238
,AGRODUTCH,EQ,         4.05,                    39066.20,9439
,AHLEAST,EQ,       169.35,                   508708.30,3046
,AHLUCONT,EQ,       284.05,                  4896126.85,17187
,AHLWEST,EQ,       130.00,                    39468.00,304
,AIAENG,EQ,       876.10,                 26181205.55,29739
,AICHAMP,BE,        37.00,                     7585.50,205
,AIFL,EQ,       295.00,                 19574219.55,66742
,AIL,EQ,       684.20,                 13358109.75,19486
,AJANTPHARM,EQ,      1309.85,                245053281.75,187695
,AJMERA,EQ,       174.95,                 25020157.45,143913
,AKSHOPTFBR,EQ,        19.15,                 66137059.25,3426971
,AKZOINDIA,EQ,      1366.05,                  5602437.20,4082
,ALANKIT,EQ,        61.15,                 38785375.45,632543
,ALBK,EQ,        67.75,                 82340562.25,1214776
,ALCHEM,EQ,        32.45,                   534756.65,16551
,ALEMBICLTD,EQ,        50.20,                 74942727.30,1526777
,ALICON,EQ,       360.95,                   416857.10,1168
,ALKALI,EQ,        65.10,                   677140.40,10625
,ALKEM,EQ,      1567.70,               1027547097.95,658233
,ALKYLAMINE,EQ,       354.20,                  1317829.40,3752
,ALLCARGO,EQ,       192.95,                 21567537.70,110818
,ALLSEC,EQ,       142.45,                  3551062.75,24831
,ALMONDZ,EQ,        13.45,                   134970.40,9934
,ALOKTEXT,EQ,         6.65,                 87827065.25,13425635
,ALPA,BE,        73.55,                  3356711.30,45191
,ALPHAGEO,EQ,       566.15,                  4626494.70,8197
,ALPSINDUS,EQ,         7.35,                   934228.60,128160
,ALSTOMT&D,EQ,       450.40,                 42144976.15,93419
,AMARAJABAT,EQ,       871.00,                385291323.10,442613
,AMBIKCO,EQ,       905.05,                  5931411.90,6515
,AMDIND,EQ,        36.25,                  9798836.65,269372
,AMRUTANJAN,EQ,       474.30,                  5424740.65,11378
,AMTEKAUTO,EQ,        49.55,                125512013.85,2533654
,AMTL,EQ,        35.00,                   967815.50,27654
,ANANDAMRUB,EQ,        29.00,                   342061.25,11899
,ANANTRAJ,EQ,        45.65,                 73245784.85,1619157
,ANDHRABANK,EQ,        63.55,                 81691827.85,1286527
,ANDHRACEMT,EQ,         9.35,                  6919273.30,739078
,ANDHRSUGAR,EQ,       144.35,                 11128472.15,76472
,ANGIND,EQ,        55.60,                 33281808.45,612807
,ANIKINDS,BE,        31.80,                   429732.15,13534
,ANKITMETAL,EQ,         2.25,                  1244632.85,578581
,ANSALAPI,EQ,        25.50,                 12961009.95,516206
,ANSALHSG,EQ,        28.45,                  1150040.40,40230
,ANTGRAPHIC,BE,          .75,                   177910.85,240272
,APARINDS,EQ,       514.00,                  5055490.10,9829
,APCOTEXIND,EQ,       233.15,                  1070055.05,4600
,APLAPOLLO,EQ,       789.45,                230732086.00,287632
,APLLTD,EQ,       677.85,                 44354712.20,65128
,APOLLOTYRE,EQ,       157.25,                207097370.95,1324704
,APOLSINHOT,BE,       220.50,                   135756.00,615
,APTECHT,EQ,        67.10,                 29169013.70,432520
,ARCHIDPLY,EQ,        61.80,                 10609476.20,174050
,ARCHIES,EQ,        30.10,                 11822565.75,390619
,ARCOTECH,EQ,       344.70,                 31510325.60,90688
,ARIES,EQ,        98.10,                  4468561.55,45669
,ARIHANT,EQ,        54.85,                    13370.90,244
,AROGRANITE,EQ,        64.05,                   617582.85,9705
,ARROWCOAT,EQ,       803.85,                  3174592.90,3947
,ARROWTEX,EQ,        34.60,                  4469146.60,130484
,ARSHIYA,EQ,        51.45,                137675916.35,2805424
,ARSSINFRA,EQ,        55.60,                 49124441.20,869639
,ARVIND,EQ,       361.15,                610245922.80,1718718
,ARVINFRA,EQ,        98.30,                 12366384.55,128030
,ASAHIINDIA,EQ,       164.10,                  3200908.60,19589
,ASAHISONG,EQ,       169.85,                  6295675.20,37613
,ASAL,EQ,        45.30,                   173792.80,3811
,ASHAPURMIN,EQ,        93.15,                 46754703.70,500697
,ASHIANA,EQ,       165.30,                  2594675.60,15684
,ASHIMASYN,EQ,        20.90,                 10943490.25,528463
,ASHOKA,EQ,       189.05,                 46832306.45,246415
,ASIANHOTNR,EQ,       135.60,                   223416.15,1648
,ASIANTILES,EQ,       179.80,                 19285976.40,106176
,ASSAMCO,EQ,         7.70,                 55521658.75,7340501
,ASTEC,EQ,       250.85,                  7647613.95,30335
,ASTRAL,EQ,       422.15,                 10516735.75,24986
,ASTRAMICRO,EQ,       143.45,                133754954.75,938947
,ASTRAZEN,EQ,      1235.50,                 71405920.75,56469
,ATFL,EQ,       554.20,                   843081.65,1542
,ATLANTA,EQ,        39.75,                  3474713.90,88431
,ATLASCYCLE,EQ,       234.70,                 77767191.85,328822
,ATNINTER,EQ,          .25,                      500.00,2000
,ATUL,EQ,      1697.10,                 55121546.45,32094
,ATULAUTO,EQ,       579.20,                 56094407.05,98292
,AURIONPRO,EQ,       206.70,                  3182020.75,15331
,AUSOMENT,EQ,        27.75,                    87688.55,3273
,AUSTRAL,EQ,          .40,                    97111.20,220250
,AUTOAXLES,EQ,       702.30,                   166416.30,237
,AUTOIND,EQ,        55.25,                  3310562.15,59498
,AUTOLITIND,EQ,        70.15,                  3448539.60,48425
,AVANTIFEED,EQ,       424.10,                 12395327.50,29133
,AVTNPL,EQ,        40.10,                 24375276.50,619116
,AXISCADES,EQ,       323.25,                 27574373.20,84659
,AXISGOLD,EQ,      2271.80,                   399230.20,176
,BAFNAPHARM,EQ,        49.80,                 36833319.90,739521
,BAGFILMS,EQ,         4.25,                   654351.25,153965
,BAJAJCORP,EQ,       431.35,                 27985541.15,64640
,BAJAJELEC,EQ,       204.60,                 43906894.30,213803
,BAJAJHIND,EQ,        18.65,                 50024485.75,2662467
,BAJFINANCE,EQ,      5997.85,                307059176.55,51120
,BALAJITELE,EQ,       136.30,                 29455363.30,215109
,BALAMINES,EQ,       159.10,                  2523309.15,16009
,BALKRISIND,EQ,       652.35,                  8310222.05,12683
,BALLARPUR,EQ,        20.85,                 66756010.35,3236506
,BALMLAWRIE,EQ,       625.60,                 18762470.20,30047
,BALPHARMA,EQ,       133.30,                 47552926.85,363304
,BALRAMCHIN,EQ,        73.85,                142185800.25,1922395
,BANARBEADS,EQ,        48.55,                    40971.85,840
,BANARISUG,EQ,      1126.95,                   939871.50,839
,BANCOINDIA,EQ,       145.15,                 12943707.30,88766
,BANG,BE,        21.80,                    24310.75,1150
,BANKBEES,EQ,      1668.14,                  5917790.83,3543
,BANSWRAS,EQ,       127.10,                   782800.95,6268
,BARTRONICS,EQ,        14.10,                  3412857.25,244060
,BASF,EQ,       931.90,                  7496293.45,8013
,BASML,EQ,       251.50,                   308911.35,1232
,BATAINDIA,EQ,       500.80,                121044333.55,240211
,BAYERCROP,EQ,      3363.90,                 20357181.95,6040
,BBL,EQ,       852.20,                 14138057.35,16653
,BBTC,EQ,       492.25,                 23343070.05,47581
,BEARDSELL,BE,       119.00,                   203230.00,1695
,BEDMUTHA,EQ,        17.25,                   165164.95,9528
,BEL,EQ,      1366.15,                363544030.35,264812
,BEML,EQ,      1271.90,                174240990.75,136825
,BEPL,EQ,        24.60,                 11299067.85,456262
,BERGEPAINT,EQ,       257.45,                167010451.80,654241
,BFINVEST,EQ,       146.55,                 10496721.05,70858
,BFUTILITIE,EQ,       688.05,                662553087.35,961519
,BGLOBAL,BE,         5.15,                   421370.85,82412
,BGRENERGY,EQ,       132.85,                 51035963.55,385903
,BHAGYNAGAR,EQ,        22.15,                   767193.65,35217
,BHARATGEAR,EQ,        94.85,                  2836897.30,30318
,BHARATRAS,EQ,      1108.40,                   631476.00,569
,BHARTISHIP,BE,        32.45,                   927406.20,28768
,BHUSANSTL,EQ,        45.35,                 42664087.40,942252
,BIL,EQ,       539.55,                  8823857.85,16344
,BILENERGY,EQ,         1.25,                     1375.00,1100
,BILPOWER,BE,         1.35,                    13500.00,10000
,BINANIIND,EQ,        78.90,                  1833994.95,23254
,BINDALAGRO,EQ,        37.65,                  1536247.40,40945
,BIOCON,EQ,       534.15,                593038234.75,1103610
,BIRLACORPN,EQ,       448.65,                  1192792.20,2652
,BIRLACOT,EQ,          .05,                   268650.20,5373004
,BIRLAERIC,BE,        56.00,                   425278.50,7825
,BIRLAMONEY,EQ,        35.30,                 16242350.60,468196
,BLBLIMITED,EQ,         5.75,                   197252.50,34950
,BLISSGVS,EQ,       180.45,                 79602427.10,440706
,BLKASHYAP,EQ,        23.20,                 16333384.25,715490
,BLUEBLENDS,BE,        47.95,                    12035.45,251
,BLUECHIP,EQ,          .40,                     1921.60,4404
,BLUEDART,EQ,      6720.00,                 18834814.95,2787
,BLUEDART,N1,        10.99,                    20331.50,1850
,BLUESTARCO,EQ,       376.95,                  2486233.15,6564
,BLUESTINFO,EQ,       248.60,                  1871107.80,7553
,BNPCPGII,MF,        10.50,                    55835.00,5080
,BODALCHEM,EQ,        58.80,                 96271359.40,1652722
,BOMDYEING,EQ,        65.45,                104229656.20,1586707
,BPL,EQ,        40.15,                 10429668.00,257259
,BRFL,EQ,       190.05,                  7060298.80,37247
,BRIGADE,EQ,       153.20,                  1719966.45,11208
,BROADCAST,EQ,         3.80,                      226.50,60
,BROOKS,EQ,       109.35,                 69072623.65,654265
,BSELINFRA,EQ,         3.95,                  1544768.55,395829
,BSL,EQ,        95.85,                  5511937.70,59192
,BSLGOLDETF,EQ,      2420.00,                   241838.00,101
,BSLIMITED,EQ,        29.20,                  7113023.05,244438
,BSLNIFTY,EQ,        90.55,                    86965.45,962
,BURNPUR,EQ,        10.50,                  8104707.30,794085
,BUTTERFLY,EQ,       291.40,                 96127950.45,330899
,BVCL,EQ,        19.50,                   184365.40,9682
,BYKE,EQ,       159.35,                 15381998.00,96714
,CADILAHC,EQ,       313.60,               1530776517.60,4874911
,CAMLINFINE,EQ,       105.65,                 51430410.20,482664
,CANDC,EQ,        15.15,                   912027.10,61294
,CANFINHOME,EQ,      1068.65,                 19359551.00,18020
,CANTABIL,EQ,        60.40,                   354643.05,5848
,CAPF,EQ,       426.95,                116917021.45,276000
,CAPLIPOINT,EQ,      1301.70,                 12881245.30,9820
,CARBORUNIV,EQ,       184.80,                  3554390.20,19212
,CAREERP,EQ,       135.60,                  2967745.00,21690
,CARERATING,EQ,      1278.70,                 17915893.45,13915
,CASTEXTECH,EQ,        14.15,                 41900428.90,2950996
,CASTROLIND,EQ,       446.80,                140532490.10,318040
,CCCL,EQ,         6.20,                   469848.90,76579
,CCHHL,EQ,        16.60,                 20832541.55,1294306
,CCL,EQ,       211.80,                 22394862.20,105071
,CEATLTD,EQ,      1061.15,                319894529.60,301981
,CEBBCO,EQ,        26.85,                 17364492.60,655122
,CELEBRITY,EQ,        16.40,                  2994182.55,180786
,CELESTIAL,EQ,        38.65,                 12520667.45,325672
,CENTENKA,EQ,       199.30,                  7601911.30,38084
,CENTEXT,EQ,         3.80,                   554159.40,145963
,CENTRALBK,EQ,        69.45,                 14347366.45,206179
,CENTUM,EQ,       652.25,                 25850662.80,38940
,CENTURYPLY,EQ,       175.05,                 43508019.90,250868
,CENTURYTEX,EQ,       597.40,                678791791.60,1142908
,CERA,EQ,      2005.05,                  4181138.75,2094
,CEREBRAINT,EQ,        22.55,                 29799420.40,1330051
,CESC,EQ,       516.20,                144350942.15,278472
,CGCL,EQ,       203.05,                  3099855.75,15880
,CHAMBLFERT,EQ,        64.05,                 40392229.00,632498
,CHEMFALKAL,EQ,       100.75,                   369684.10,3686
,CHENNPETRO,EQ,       198.55,                 50062110.60,250808
,CHOLAFIN,EQ,       641.90,                213069363.25,327930
,CHROMATIC,EQ,         4.45,                  3892817.50,880075
,CIGNITITEC,EQ,       458.10,                 18109909.70,39492
,CIMMCO,EQ,        87.15,                  1560604.55,17851
,CINELINE,EQ,        26.40,                  2431574.90,94834
,CINEVISTA,EQ,         5.55,                   455065.65,81214
,CLNINDIA,EQ,       779.05,                  4600514.85,5911
,CNOVAPETRO,EQ,        34.30,                    66609.70,1956
,COFFEEDAY,EQ,       282.45,                 49008604.70,173477
,COMPUSOFT,EQ,        12.55,                   453673.35,36745
,CONSOFINVT,EQ,        74.95,                  1489460.30,20020
,CORDSCABLE,EQ,        67.75,                 22800280.45,346342
,COROMANDEL,EQ,       185.85,                 51043853.15,273556
,CORPBANK,EQ,        42.55,                  3444833.90,80891
,COSMOFILMS,EQ,       304.60,                356127682.55,1171592
,COUNCODOS,BE,         8.30,                   376742.55,44474
,COX&KINGS,EQ,       242.60,                 61654916.20,255452
,CPSEETF,EQ,        21.59,                  1773690.03,82492
,CREATIVEYE,EQ,         5.10,                   117468.75,23250
,CREST,EQ,        56.75,                   147384.15,2598
,CRISIL,EQ,      1981.10,                 10172163.80,5174
,CRMFGETF,EQ,      2425.00,                     4850.00,2
,CROMPGREAV,EQ,       198.80,                921444750.45,4654814
,CTE,BE,       154.10,                  2169573.90,14079
,CUB,EQ,        90.90,                 15297453.35,167955
,CUBEXTUB,BE,        15.50,                    32153.00,2026
,CURATECH,EQ,         8.40,                    59550.00,7000
,CYBERMEDIA,EQ,        13.95,                     8105.00,582
,CYBERTECH,EQ,        61.45,                 10840437.00,176584
,CYIENT,EQ,       487.80,                 11653090.90,23648
,DAAWAT,EQ,       261.50,                  3822130.45,14572
,DALMIABHA,EQ,       835.70,                  6417961.75,7691
,DALMIASUG,EQ,        64.20,                  3582051.00,54842
,DATAMATICS,EQ,        71.20,                 14602458.90,203186
,DBCORP,EQ,       326.05,                   622307.25,1902
,DBREALTY,EQ,        58.00,                 11155152.30,191200
,DBSTOCKBRO,EQ,        24.30,                   148880.45,6119
,DCBBANK,EQ,        79.95,                 51677791.20,644570
,DCM,EQ,        97.55,                  8041609.15,82877
,DCMSHRIRAM,EQ,       142.00,                  8991433.05,63756
,DCW,EQ,        29.00,                159552554.40,5596093
,DECCANCE,EQ,       751.10,                  7406651.90,9956
,DEEPAKFERT,EQ,       159.85,                  6622480.15,41452
,DEEPAKNTR,EQ,        74.40,                  2572272.75,34549
,DEEPIND,EQ,       178.45,                 26136054.60,146647
,DELTACORP,EQ,        84.40,                460401276.50,5420514
,DELTAMAGNT,EQ,        31.85,                     2594.25,83
,DEN,EQ,       109.20,                  3386494.60,30876
,DENABANK,EQ,        40.50,                  7627306.95,187704
,DENORA,EQ,       438.40,                 57277027.65,129564
,DHAMPURSUG,EQ,        71.75,                 22303804.65,309680
,DHANBANK,EQ,        22.30,                  5642261.30,252586
,DHANUKA,EQ,       517.10,                  6333222.15,12255
,DHARSUGAR,EQ,        22.45,                    87324.85,3865
,DHFL,EQ,       231.50,                 90444361.35,389698
,DHUNINV,EQ,       151.50,                   118895.90,784
,DIAPOWER,EQ,        43.15,                  4182586.50,96426
,DICIND,EQ,       724.75,                 14511975.70,20148
,DIGJAM,EQ,        17.15,                 61485459.50,3603570
,DISHMAN,EQ,       350.10,                730946555.65,2088496
,DISHTV,EQ,       100.10,                305306937.50,3064022
,DLF,EQ,       118.40,               2839024394.30,23815902
,DLINKINDIA,EQ,       176.15,                  3472310.95,19734
,DOLPHINOFF,EQ,       130.10,                 10060995.35,75566
,DONEAR,EQ,        38.15,                 12620651.05,331733
,DPL,EQ,        84.05,                  1459746.80,17362
,DPSCLTD,EQ,        12.55,                   474083.85,37605
,DQE,EQ,        39.70,                 22841938.50,573296
,DREDGECORP,EQ,       408.05,                 78304107.55,193733
,DSKULKARNI,EQ,       108.90,                 14380875.85,129121
,DSSL,EQ,        15.00,                     4410.00,294
,DTIL,EQ,       319.40,                  3063055.85,9545
,DUNCANSLTD,BE,        16.50,                    15542.50,933
,DWARKESH,EQ,       110.15,                  9706871.30,87676
,DYNAMATECH,EQ,      2380.05,                  2496270.15,1044
,DYNATECH,EQ,        17.15,                   901258.90,52848
,EASTSILK,EQ,         3.65,                   408175.05,112303
,EASUNREYRL,EQ,        52.85,                  5640905.40,107869
,ECEIND,EQ,       152.55,                   908248.40,5969
,ECLERX,EQ,      1391.95,                 11028090.15,7889
,ECLFINANCE,N7,      1283.00,                    11547.00,9
,ECLFINANCE,N2,      1271.00,                   169930.00,134
,ECLFINANCE,N3,      1082.00,                    64882.60,60
,ECLFINANCE,N4,      1325.01,                    13250.10,10
,ECLFINANCE,N5,      1081.00,                  1909683.00,1767
,ECLFINANCE,NB,      1008.20,                   295156.74,292
,ECLFINANCE,N1,      1037.00,                   112827.66,109
,EDELWEISS,EQ,        56.45,                 17014672.25,300647
,EDL,EQ,       100.25,                 10482945.10,104145
```

Comment: Do your know your offsets absolutely (i.e. read from line number x to y) or do you only know the contents of those lines?

Comment: Thanks for the reply actullay i want to extract starting from 

Nifty 50,      7963.20,      7924.55,      7937.55,      7781.10,      7791.30,-171.9
to
Nifty50 Value 20,      3580.10,      3559.70,      3570.55,      3503.05,      3508.70,-71.4

Comment: So i thought it to go from this line 

,INDEX,PREVIOUS CLOSE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,GAIN/LOSS

till the end of 

,ADVANCES,533  , this is the standard format they will folllow and send the file daily.

Comment: So you only know the textual contents of your delimiting lines but not their offsets?

Comment: Or could you please tell me if it is possible to extract all Nifty 50 ,Nifty Auto , Nifty Metal ... etc with their values  into  a bean ?? as far as i know this headings will remain standard and will not chnage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using piped streams. It may not be that pretty, but it should get the job done in a scalable way:

```
final String startToken = ",INDEX,PREVIOUS CLOSE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,GAIN/LOSS";
final String endToken = ",ADVANCES,533";    

final PipedWriter pipedWriter = new PipedWriter();     
PipedReader pipedReaderTmp = null;
try {
    pipedReaderTmp = new PipedReader(pipedWriter);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something smart
}
final PipedReader pipedReader = pipedReaderTmp;

// Consumer    
new Thread(new Runnable() {        
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(pipedReader)) {            
            while (true) {                        
                String[] line = csvReader.readNext(); // blocks until the next line is available
                if (line == null) break; // end of stream has been reached
                //
                // Nonsense output routine follows; replace with your own logic
                //
                for (String component : line) {
                    System.out.print(component + '\t');
                }
                System.out.println();
             }            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do something smart
        }        
    }
}).start();

// Producer
new Thread(new Runnable() {        
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"))) {                        
            String line = null;

            // consume everything up to and including the start token
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (startToken.equals(line)) break;
            }

            // consume everything up to and including the end token
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (endToken.equals(line)) break;
                pipedWriter.write(line + '\n');            
            }
            pipedWriter.close();            
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // do something smart
        }        
    }
}).start();
```

This code creates two threads. A *producer* reads the relevant parts of the input file (lower part of the above snippet) and pipes this data into a *consumer* (upper thread) which processes it as if it was coming directly from a file on disk.

Comment: first thanks for your hard work ,i ran your code and it works very very nice which i can directly use , is itpossible to break once it reaches "ADVANCES" ?? i tried to put a break but its not stopping .

Comment: @Kiran What do you mean by "once it reaches"? It does break once it sees the `endToken` in the input file on a separate line. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: no problem i can solve it now , i can put some debugger points and do the task , thanks a lot for guiding me to compleet the task , this was a great idea .

Comment: @Kiran You are welcome. If you need to split the file into distinct sections which you process independently (i.e. your file is actually a concatenation of several CSV files), you may simply put those two threads in a loop and adjust the tokens for each iteration. There are smarter ways to do this (since thread creation is expensive) but it'll work.